# How to use 'a' tags and noscript properly for alternative content?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble passing my solution to be W3C valid.
I'd like to show alternative URLs for visitors who disable JS by this way:

```
<a href="javascript:void();"><noscript><a href="nojspage.html"></noscript>some anchor text</a>
```

It works flawlessly - a 'popup div' is opened for visitors with JS enabled, all others are directed to the html page.

However the validator breaks at that point due to 'illegal nesting of the a tag'.

So I'd like to use one anchor text (which is much longer than this example) with multiple a tags (one calling the JS, the other as a regular link). Displaying the anchor text by JS is not an option because I've got many similar links in the navigation menu.

I just wonder how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use **progressive enhancement** instead of `noscript`.

Start with a regular link. Then layer JS on top, and stop the link being followed if the JS is successful.

```
<a href="nojspage.html">some anchor text</a>
<script>

    function myJsFunction(evt) {
        // Do something with JS
        evt.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from being followed
    }

    document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", myJsFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: OP is using the noscript tag correctly. While you're pointing OP to a more scalable solution we have no idea what the project looks like or whether it calls for other solutions. [The noscript tag is a 100% valid way to display a message and a link to alternative content for Javascript-free users.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript) Your solution has no message for users without Javascript.

Comment: @thordarson — The OP is trying to use `<noscript>` (with invalid code) to provide **the same message** but **different link behaviour** to users with and without JS. This is a good way to achieve that. Trying to substitute a different start tag for the anchor is not.

Answer (score -1):

your noscript tag is closed before a tag closed that is why validator complaining

Comment: No. The validator is complaining because you can't put an `<a>` inside another `<a>`. The early close tag is the **next** error, not the one the question is asking about.